# World Scene Lights On, No Texture

Tags: append

[image]

Blender version 3.5.1.  I made an ocean. I appended a unicorn model into it.

When the world scene light is on the unicorn loses its texture but not colour.The texture's there with the world scene off. It's the same in rendered preview and material preview.

Any ideas why this is happening?

[image]

Comment: Screenshots or even GIFs would help understand your question. Or even your file if you think it might be hard to get what's happening. Please consider sharing your .blend file with use, you can do so by uploading it to [Blend-Exchange](https://blend-exchange.com/) and add the provided text into your post.

Comment: I did put an image in but I guess I did something wrong. It worked this time.

Comment: Can you share the blend file? ( plz remember to pack the images)

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=94SSo9Lg" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/94SSo9Lg/)

Answer (score 1):

It's because of your HDRI, it's very bright on its whole surface, if you have lights 360° around your object you won't have any shadow, while the *Material Preview* HDRI selected has the light coming from a more defined direction. If I take your current HDR and paint on it to make the light comes from a direction, here is what it gives:

[image]

In the new file that you share, the HDRI image is still the same, it is called *Sky1.png*, which is bright all around, it will prevent any shadow and therefore you won't be able to see any fold on your plastic object, to fix that you need to choose another HDRI image:

[image]

If you want a different HDRI for the reflection, so that the sea is affected by an HDRI and the object is affected by another HDRI, you can mix 2 HDRIs and use an *Input > Light Path > Is Reflection Ray* as *Factor*:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I'm pretty new at this and I can't figure out what you're talking about. How do I fix this? What window should I be in and what do I adjust?

Comment: You need to change the HDRI you're using, open the Shader Editor, switch it to World instead of Object, and in the Environment Texture node, load a new image (or paint on the image that is used, as I did)

Comment: I did what I think you said and it just darkens everything. I added a 100000w point light and it still won't get clear with good highlights. Even what you did, the image is still dull with no highlights like in the first image. I've used this exact same water with other appended objects and there's no problem. How do I get the unicorn to look like the first image? Thanks for helping.

Comment: could you please pack your image (File > External Data > Pack Resources) and share again?

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=v9Kx0j40" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/v9Kx0j40/)

Comment: thanks, I've edited my answer, you have not change the HDRI image, you need to upload another one, the current one won't create any shadow as it is 360° bright

Comment: When I change the HDRI image it changes the colour etc. of the water. I have that water in too many scenes to change it now. Thanks for your effort. (o:

Comment: @Schming In that case maybe read my edit